# How to delete a STL list of pointers?

Tags: c++, list, memory-leaks, stl, iterator

I have a a list of pairs.
Is it a good idea to iterate over the list and delete the first and the second element?
The objects in it are allocated with new.

```
list<pair<string,GraphObject*>>* table;
for(i=0; i< length; i++){
    it = table[i].begin();
    while(it != table[i].end()){
        delete (*it).second;
        delete &(*it).first;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
string is not allocated with new, I know now I don't have to delete it.
Is it okay to delete the second this way?

Comment: how can the `string` object in each pair be allocated with `new`? It is not a pointer type...

Comment: Thanks Andy, you're completely right. Question is edited.

Comment: first, it is very bad to do `delete &(*it).first;`. You are trying to deallocate an object with automatic storage (i.e. allocated on the stack) as if it was allocated on the heap. Second, you delete those objects but I don't see you removing the corresponding entries from the list, which will leave you with dangling pointers in the list itself. Third, you should not use naked (raw) pointers, but rather smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` to handle an object's lifetime. `new` and `delete` are almost never needed and almost always discouraged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you your actual need is `std::map` with smart pointer

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<GraphObject>> table;
```

To clear table, you simply write:

```
table.clear();
```

If you have to work with std::list, still use smart pointers, you still only need to call `table.clear();` to clear whole table.

```
std::list<std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<GraphObject>>> table;
```

Comment: @JohnSmith: Who do you have to assassinate to use a sensible data structure instead of a list? What are your chances of getting away with doing it? [of course I'm not serious, *but* really, truly, and seriously: a list is almost certainly the *wrong* structure to use here.]

Answer (score 1):

The `string` is *not* allocated with `new`, it's a data member of the `pair`. Your second `delete` is an error.

Maybe it's a copy of a `string` object that was allocated with `new`, but if so then you probably leaked the original long ago.

For the first delete -- it is a good idea to delete objects that were allocated with `new`, if and only if you don't need them any more. You don't say whether you still need these objects (i.e. whether you still have other pointers to them). However, it's an even better idea to use smart pointers to help manage memory.

Comment: It is in the destructor that I want to free everything in the list.

Comment: @John: the destructor of what? Anyway, my point is that only you know whether or not it's the right time to delete the objects, I can't tell you.

Comment: Yes, I don't need the objects.
I'm implementing the destructor of a HashTable.

Comment: @John: great, delete them then :-) But also consider smart pointers. Their job is to delete things for you, and used correctly you won't have to loop over the list, just delete the `table`. Use a smart pointer for that too, and you might not need to write a destructor at all.

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks Mr. Steve Jessop!

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the first part of the pair because it isn't a pointer; your code shouldn't even compile. What you *can* do is delete the whole table when you're done.

```
list<pair<string,GraphObject*>>* table;
for(i=0; i< length; i++){
    it = table[i].begin();
    while(it != table[i].end()){
        delete (*it).second;
    }
}
delete table;
```

As to whether you should delete the `GraphObject*` second member of the pair, that would depend on whether there are other copies of the pointer that will be deleted elsewhere. Presumably there aren't so your original code is correct. As pointed out in another answer, it would be easier to use a smart pointer instead so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: "your code shouldn't even compile" - it's `delete &(*it).first` (note the ampersand). Which is certainly wrong, but provides the right type for `delete` so I think it should compile.